# I can't display my image on my local browser via Vue3, No errors reported in the console, element also has a corresponding image list

Tags: html, vue.js, browser, vuejs3

my code is here:

```html
<script setup lang='ts' > 
    import {reactive, ref} from 'vue' 
    import position from '@/assets/images/R3.png'  
</script> 
<template> 
    <image v-bind:src="position" width = "500" height = '600'></image> 
</template>
```

And I also upload the screeshot of elements that it is working in my browser, you can see it is showing `<image src="/src/assets/images/R3.png" width="500" height="600"></image>`   up, but I can't see anything on my screen HAHA.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOG0N.png)

I try both `require()` and `new URL()` methods, but the former doesn't work, the latter doesn't help either. I need some help to display my image normally.

Comment: I am sorry this code look so messy cause by I am a beginner...

Comment: The correct html tag is `<img>`, not `<image>` ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, It's me too careless.... ^^